# Open-source projects using C++ and XML data binding

Tags: c++, data-binding, open-source, xsd

I'm looking for open-source projects that make use of two things: (1) C++ and (2) XML data binding. For those who don't know, data binding tools make use of XML schema and code generators such as [Codesynthesis xsd](http://www.codesynthesis.com/products/xsd), [Liquid Technologies](http://www.liquid-technologies.com/Xml-Data-Binding.aspx). I know [CIAO/DAnCE](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/CIAO.html) project, an implementation of CORBA Component Model that uses XML Schema Compiler ([XSC](http://www.dre.vanderbilt.edu/~boris/xsc)) but I'm hoping to find more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tried  http://www.codesynthesis.com/products/xsd/ a few months back and I thought the resulting C++ interface was pretty clean. (It's style is similar to STL / boost APIs)

Other than that the gSOAP toolkit appears to have something too. ( http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soapdoc2.html#tth_sEc1.4 )

Answer (score 0):

Some open source projects that use Codesynthesis XSD are listed on this wiki page:
 http://wiki.codesynthesis.com/Open_source_projects_that_use_XSD